# Can one do response.flush() when using ajax?

Tags: ajax, vbscript

When loading a page with lots of data (for example a very large page), I use

```
Response.Buffer = True
....

response.Flush()
```

So that each table row displays as its ready.

But when I have a load the content via `ajax`, this does not seem to work - it just loads in one shot. Is this at all doable in an `ajax` context?

Comment: See [A: AJAX / ASP - Update Progress Panel - Response.Flush](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7664674/692942).

Comment: mmm. thanks. i figured that would be the answer :-(